Android Studio. Unable to start AVD: "Failed to process .ini file ...quickbootChoice.ini for reading."
When creating the new AVD or starting the one created before I receive the error "The emulator process for AVD [NAME] has terminated." (Under [NAME] it mentions my device name)
The problem first appears on Android Studio 2022.1 and still present with Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2024.1\log\idea.log:
2024-07-02 14:55:12,039 [ 300505]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 35 - C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_7a_API_35 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300

2024-07-02 14:55:12,076 [ 300542]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 35 - Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db, detection is enabled for process: 9572

2024-07-02 14:55:12,076 [ 300542]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 35 - Android emulator version 34.2.15.0 (build_id 11906825) (CL:N/A)

2024-07-02 14:55:12,076 [ 300542]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 35 - Found systemPath C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-35\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\

2024-07-02 14:55:13,181 [ 301647]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 35 - Ignore IPv6 address: a00e:c0da:5902:0:b0e6:bfda:5902:0 (2x)

2024-07-02 14:55:13,181 [ 301647]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 35 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\User\.android\avd\..\avd\Pixel_7a_API_35.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.

2024-07-02 14:55:14,184 [ 302650]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 35 - added library vulkan-1.dll

2024-07-02 14:55:17,377 [ 305843]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 35 - Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

2024-07-02 14:55:17,377 [ 305843]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 7a API 35 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073740791

As for
Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\User\.android\avd\..\avd\Pixel_7a_API_35.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
I do not have "quickbootChoice.ini" file there.
I have tried:

Disabled the Windows Defender
I have enabled Hyper-V -> did not help
I have removed all the Android system variables except for PATH -> did not help
C:\Users\User\appdata\local\Android\Sdk\build-tools C:\Users\User\appdata\local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools C:\Users\User\appdata\local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools


Had exactly same problem after complete new installation of studio64x 2024.1.1 including emulator and avd on Windows Home 11 on a HP 17-cp0157ng notebook.
Found an answer which helped me in Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005):
Edit [AVD-PATH][AVD-NAME]\config.ini and set
hw.gpu.mode=off (original value was auto)
This also solved a problem I had since months:
Emulator start was possible only with disconnected docking station.

You are the ONE! I would not even think the link you have shared is related to my question. Thank you.

i found that answer is using software instead:
enter image description here
But it take too long to render and i don't know how to run avd with hardware graphic. It take me several day to find the answer T.T

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
